# Measuring height of text using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, text

I want to measure height of text fields on images programmatically (check attachment).

[example-image-attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFxXQ.png)

Is there any ideas how to do it using PIL/etc.?

Comment: Are you measuring scanned documents? Or screen grabs?

Comment: @MarkSetchell screenshots